# Comparing Garch and Neural Networks with Time Series

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, finance, autoregressive-models

I want to compare how garch models time series versus a neural network.  I have my garch model:

```
    garch<-ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)),         
    mean.model=list(armaOrder= c(0,0), include.mean=FALSE),            
    distribution.model= "std")
    garch_fit<-ugarchfit(spec=garch,data=currency)

    print(garch_fit)
```

So I have my data which is a foreign currency converted to US dollars and I scaled the raw prices to be in terms of the mean of all prices.

The next step of my project is to fit my currency data to a neural network and then compare which model works better--garch or neural net. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Isn't this confounding ideas? I think you implement a GARCH model as an RNN. "Network" doesn't really mean anything except layers and activations and usually autodiff. There are no assumptions about the loss (noise model or anything). 

I would be interested in seeing someone implementing GARCH as tensorflow rnn for example.

Answer (score 0):

For fitting data to neural nets in R, there are several specialized packages to choose from: nnet, neuralnet, deepnet (which specializes in DNNs), h2o, mxnet. You could also always use TensorFlow or Keras in R to develop very specific kinds of neural networks if you so desire.

In the past I've used nnet, neuralnet, and Keras. For quick projects and rapid prototyping, `library(neuralnet)` works great for beginners. You can very rapidly produce, train, and utilize a neuralnet of your design (within certain constraints). As an example:

```
nn_model <- neuralnet(formula = my_form, data = training_data, hidden = c(2, 3))
```

Where `my_form` could be something like `formula("currency ~ indVar1 + indVar2 +...)`, the training_data is the same data that you're training the GARCH model on, and hidden is a vector representing the size of each hidden layer in your neural network (depending on what structure you wanted, nature of problem, etc.)

What you should then do is run both your GARCH model and the neural network on the same test/validation data (separate and distinct from your training data) and evaluate their performance through metrics like *accuracy*, *precision*, and *recall*.

You can run the generated models on the test data with:

```
garch_out <- ugarchforecast(garch_fit, data = test_data[, -1], n.ahead = 10)
nn_out <- compute(x = nn_model, covariate = test_data[, -1])
```

and evaluate them on a discrete or continuous basis, though with a regression it's likely you want to observe the similarity between the output of each of these models and the expected value of `test_data[,1]` through the lens of normal time series analysis tools like residual analysis, R^2, adjusted R^2 and other goodness-of-fit characteristics.

Comment: But for the formula("currency ~ indVar1 + indVar2 +...) part of the function, I am not sure what to include here, as my data is a time series and thus only have one column which is mean returns of the currency.  Can I still use this model if I don't have multiple variables?

Comment: If your working with forecasting a time series based solely on itself, with no other explanatory variables, your indicator variables would most likely be lagged versions of the time series in question. Depending on your applications you'd usually go one unit in time back (say one day) or more or less, you can also provide data for multiple lags, like one day, two days, one week, all at the same time. 
In the case of GARCH, the amount of data it has going into it depends upon the specified ARMA components. You might want to match that within your neural network.